How to filter out a key from a second level object of a nested array of objects
I am trying to filter out a key, in this case, count from a nested array of objects.
I have
let test  = [
 {
  "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
  "label": "Sector2",
  "options": {
   "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob",
    "count": 1
   },
   "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck",
    "count": 1
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow"
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish"
 }
]

 test = test.filter(item => item[0].options['count']);

but I am getting Cannot read properties of undefined
I am trying to filter out count from all elements of test that have options
desired output is
Thanks
[
 {
  "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
  "label": "Sector2",
  "options": {
   "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob"
   },
   "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student"
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck"
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow"
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish"
 }
]


It's not clear what you're trying to do.

The answer to following question might already provide a generic solution ... "How to selectively copy properties from a deep nested data structure?"

I am trying to filter out count from all elements of test that have options

sorry I edited my question

To which line is the error referring? I suggest logging your item to determine if it's what you are expecting.

filter() is used to filter a portion of an array, not to delete nested keys of an object.

The easiest way to achieve your desired result it to:

Loop over each object
If this object has options
Loop over each options
Use delete to delete the count of the current object



const data = [{"id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8", "label": "Sector2", "options": {"62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {"index": 0, "value": "Bob", "label": "Bob", "count": 1 }, "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {"index": 1, "value": "Student", "label": "Student", "count": 1 }, "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {"index": 2, "value": "BBB", "label": "BBB", "count": 1 }, "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {"index": 3, "value": "Orange Duck", "label": "Orange Duck", "count": 1 } } }, {"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485", "label": "Brown Cow" }, {"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ", "label": "Red Fish" } ];

for (let i in data) {
    if (data[i]?.options) {
        for (let j in data[i].options) {
            delete data[i].options[j]?.count;
        }
    }
}

console.log(data);




Very clear, and very understandable! Thank you

A generic solution to the OP's problem does, regardless of the provided data-structure, structurally clone such an object while omitting any property which matches the provided set of to be omitted keys/property-names ...


let sampleData = [{
  "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
  "label": "Sector2",
  "options": {
    "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
      "index": 0,
      "value": "Bob",
      "label": "Bob",
      "count": 1
    },
    "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
      "index": 1,
      "value": "Student",
      "label": "Student",
      "count": 1
    },
    "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
      "index": 2,
      "value": "BBB",
      "label": "BBB",
      "count": 1
    },
    "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
      "index": 3,
      "value": "Orange Duck",
      "label": "Orange Duck",
      "count": 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow"
}, {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish"
}];

console.log(
  cloneDataAndIgnoreKeys(
    sampleData,
    new Set(['count']),
  )
);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
<script>
function cloneDataAndIgnoreKeys(
  dataSource, ignoredKeys = new Set, dataTarget = {}
) {
  if (Array.isArray(dataSource)) {

    dataTarget = dataSource
      .map(item =>
        cloneDataAndIgnoreKeys(item, ignoredKeys)
      );
  } else if (!!dataSource && (typeof dataSource === 'object')) {

    dataTarget = Object
      .entries(dataSource)
      .reduce((target, [key, value]) => {

        if (!ignoredKeys.has(key)) {
          target[key] =
            cloneDataAndIgnoreKeys(value, ignoredKeys);
        }
        return target;

      }, dataTarget);

  } else {
    dataTarget = dataSource;
  }
  return dataTarget;
}
</script>




You could destructure the objects and remove unwanted property.


const
    filter = ({ count, ...o }) => Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(o)
        .map(([k, v]) => [k, v && typeof v === 'object' ? filter(v) : v])
    ),
    data = [{ id: "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8", label: "Sector2", options: { "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": { index: 0, value: "Bob", label: "Bob", count: 1 }, "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": { index: 1, value: "Student", label: "Student", count: 1 }, c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4: { index: 2, value: "BBB", label: "BBB", count: 1 }, c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA: { index: 3, value: "Orange Duck", label: "Orange Duck", count: 1 } } }, { id: "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485", label: "Brown Cow" }, { id: "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ", label: "Red Fish" }],
    result = data.map(filter);

 console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }





use the map function to iterate over your array.
Generate a copy of your options.
Utilize a for-in loop to inspect object properties and eliminate them
from the array.
When incorporating this code into your project, ensure to include the
following adjustments to avoid type errors.it online compiler is not accept type any.


delete (option as any).count;
(newItem.options as any)?.optionKey;

Thanks


let test  = [
 {
  "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
  "label": "Sector2",
  "options": {
   "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob",
    "count": 1
   },
   "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck",
    "count": 1
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow"
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish"
 }
];

let filteredTest = test.map(item => {
    if (item?.options) {

        const newItem = { ...item };

    for (const optionKey in newItem.options) 
  {

   if (newItem.options.hasOwnProperty(optionKey)) 
  {

  const option = newItem.options[optionKey];
   if (option && 'count' in option) {
        delete option?.count;
       }
     }
   }

return newItem;

   }

 return item;

});
console.log(filteredTest);




You can do it as a one-liner like this:


const data = [{"id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8", "label": "Sector2", "options": {"62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {"index": 0, "value": "Bob", "label": "Bob", "count": 1 }, "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {"index": 1, "value": "Student", "label": "Student", "count": 1 }, "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {"index": 2, "value": "BBB", "label": "BBB", "count": 1 }, "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {"index": 3, "value": "Orange Duck", "label": "Orange Duck", "count": 1 } } }, {"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485", "label": "Brown Cow" }, {"id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ", "label": "Red Fish" } ];

data.forEach(i => Object.values(i.options ?? {}).forEach(i => delete i.count))

console.log(data);




Sweet, you used the nullish coalescing operator



let test  = [
 {
  "id": "c3c6f410f58e5836431b473ebcf134756232d04f2bf35edff8",
  "label": "Sector2",
  "options": {
   "62f92fab79ac81d933765bd0bbc4a1f5ea26cb3a088bcb4e6e": {
    "index": 0,
    "value": "Bob",
    "label": "Bob",
    "count": 1
   },
   "2fe91aa3567c0d04c521dcd2fc7e40d7622bb8c3f594d503da": {
    "index": 1,
    "value": "Student",
    "label": "Student",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc543e4": {
    "index": 2,
    "value": "BBB",
    "label": "BBB",
    "count": 1
   },
   "c59ea1159f33b91a7f6edc6925be5e373fc54AAA": {
    "index": 3,
    "value": "Orange Duck",
    "label": "Orange Duck",
    "count": 1
   }
  }
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e951709485",
  "label": "Brown Cow"
 },
 {
  "id": "f794c6a52e793ee6f5c42cd5df6b4435236e3495e95170ZZZ",
  "label": "Red Fish"
 }
]



test = test.map(o => !o.options ? o : Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(o.options).map(([key, {
    count,
    ...rest
  }]) => [
    key, rest
  ])
));

console.log(test)



